# helper_method not working with ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have been trying to understand ActionCable for the past 2 months.

I have a helper method *:current_user* defined in

> app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

end
```

When calling it from

> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```html
<%= current_user.id %>
```

it displays: **1** for example. 
However, when I bring *:current_user* to Action Cable, it displays empty or *nil*.

> app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

```html
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user
      logger.add_tags "ActionCable", "User: #{current_user.id}"
    end

  end
end
```

**Terminal:** 
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
There was an exception - NoMethodError(undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass)

Thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the doc you provided, you will know that identified_by is not a method for a Channel instance. It is a method for Actioncable::Connection. From Rails guide for Actioncable Overview, this is how a Connection class looks like:

**#app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module 
 ApplicationCable class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
 identified_by :current_user

  def connect 
      self.current_user = find_verified_user 
  end 

  private
  def find_verified_user 
   if current_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
       current_user 
   else
       reject_unauthorized_connection 
   end 
  end
 end 
end
```

As you can see, current_user is not available here. Instead, you have to create a current_user here in connection.
The websocket server doesn't have a session, but it can read the same cookies as the main app. So I guess, you need to save cookie after authentication. Thanks ASAP..

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and quick clarification @max

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between your ApplicationController (or controllers in general), helpers and ActionCable. They are completely separate concepts.

Controllers respond to regular HTTP requests. They inherit from `ActionController::Base`, `ActionController::Api` or `ActionController::Metal`.

Helpers are just modules located in your `app/helpers` directory which are included in the view context. Which is the context that controllers provide the view. When you call `helper_method :current_user` you make that method available in the controller as well.

But an ActionCable Connenction is not a controller. Nor does it have anything really to do with a controller or MVC.

> Connections form the foundation of the client-server relationship. For
>   every WebSocket accepted by the server, a connection object is
>   instantiated.

Websockets is a completely seperate protocol from HTTP.

While you could include your helpers in a Connection class since they are just modules its not going to help you here as the [session middleware is not available in ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#notes). So there ain't no way that little session based auth you built off some tutorial is magically going to start working in ActionCable.

You can still access the cookies though through `cookies.signed` so what you need to do is modify your auth system so that it sets a signed HTTP cookie as well which you then read in ActionCable.

Comment: This is why encapsulation sucks. Thanks, OOP.

Comment: @weltschmerz that's the wrong takeaway...

Answer (score 1):

Helper methods only available in your views. Remember that.